# Converting string to two dimensional array and shuffling

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I'm using Wordpress and Advanced Custom Fields. My objective is to take the content from inside the field and convert it to a two-dimensional array, then shuffle it. The content is a series of shortcodes that looks like `[contentcards url="..." options="..."]`.

```
function shuffle_content_cards($content) {
  // $content = get_the_content();
  $short_codes = array();
  $the_short_code = '';
  $content = str_replace('<p>', '', $content);
  $content = str_replace('</p>', '', $content);
  if (strpos($content, ']') !== false ) {
  for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($content); $i++) {
    if ($content[$i] == '[') {
      $start = $i;
    }
    else if ($content[$i] == ']') {
      $end = $i;
      $the_short_code = substr($content, $start, $end+1);
      $content = str_replace($the_short_code, ' ', $content );
      array_push($short_codes, $the_short_code);
// echo $the_short_code;
    }
  }
}
  shuffle($short_codes);
  $content = implode(' ', $short_codes);
  // echo $content;
  return $content;
}
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'shuffle_content_cards', 0);
```

I have it working as far as shuffling the array and outputting it, the only problem I have is that the last shortcode is not displayed. There are 7 short codes in the content and the last is no where to be found.

Here's the result of var_dump($short_codes);

```
array(3) {

    [0]=> string(169) "[contentcards url="https://www.gotimelinr.com/" custom_image="https://creativesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/timelinr-project-manager.jpg" custom_title="Timelinr"]"

    [1]=> string(549) " [contentcards url="https://ora.pm" custom_image="https://creativesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ora-project-management-software.png" custom_title="Ora"] [contentcards url="https://monday.com/" custom_image="https://creativesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/monday-project-management.png" custom_title="Monday" custom_description="monday.com is a tool that simplify the way teams work together - Manage workload, track projects, move work forward, communicate with people - Adopt a management tool that people actually love to use."]"

    [2]=> string(703) " [contentcards url="https://www.outplanr.com/" custom_image="https://www.outplanr.com/img/screenshots/1.jpg" custom_title="Outplanr"] [contentcards url="https://hitask.com/" custom_image="https://creativesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/hitask-project-manager-software.jpg" custom_title="Hitask"] [contentcards url="https://freedcamp.com/" custom_image="https://creativesfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/freedcamp-project-manager.jpg" custom_title="Freedcamp" custom_description="Our mission is to empower people to achieve great things together​. The notion of simple collaboration has been lost and split into hundreds of fragments with countless tools trying to solve each piece."]"
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($short_codes);`? Does it include all of the s shortcodes?

Comment: I changed my question to include the return value of var_dump($short_codes); It looks like there are only 3, there should be 7 though.

Comment: It looks like your `var_dump($shortcodes)` has 3 root elements, but you have 6 `contentcards url=` in your data. Maybe you need to change the way you're parsing `$content`?

Comment: I think you are right, maybe if I could just use preg_split() and find a regex to match '['.

Comment: Trying to use '  $parts = preg_split('@(?=[)@', $content, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
' but I can't seem to capture the delimiter, any advice?

Comment: I'm not very well versed in `regex`. You may need to report your question with updated code using `regex` and tag it for `regex`

Comment: I'd prefer to see a [mcve] that presents `$content` and the desired output.